# Spotfire - Calculate average only if there are minimum 3 values

Tags: average, calculated-columns, spotfire, tibco

I want to create a cross table in Spotfire where in which Average is calculated only when there are at least 3 values. If there are no values or less than 3 values the average should be blank.

```
+-------+-----+---------+
| Month | Age | Average |
+-------+-----+---------+
|     1 |  10 |         |
|     2 |  11 |         |
|     3 |   2 |     7.7 |
|     4 |     |         |
|     5 |  13 |         |
|     6 |  14 |         |
|     7 |     |         |
|     8 |  19 |         |
|     9 |  20 |         |
|    10 |  21 |      20 |
+-------+-----+---------+
```

[image]

Comment: What would be on the category axis of the cross table? Is this the actual data set or what you expect the cross table to look like?

Comment: @scsimon This is the actual data and I am adding an image how the output should look like. Thanks for looking into this one.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to group by Month, and then have something like this as your aggregation:

If(Count()>2,Avg([Age]),null) as [AverageAge_3Min]

Comment: Hi Chelsea, no. I want to calculate average only if there are minimum 3 values. so for eg: Month 1 has no previous value, month 2 has only 2 value, month 3 has 3 values which are 2,11,10, then it should calculate average. Similarly month 4,5,6,7,8,9 won't get calculated since there are no previous 3 values.